# Get previously bounded data

Tags: svg, d3.js

Assume I'm using a slightly modified version of the [example code from the selection.data() API docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data),

```
var matrix = [
   [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
   [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
   [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
   [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];

var tr = d3.select("body").append("table").selectAll("tr")
    .data(matrix, function(d) { return d[0]; })
  .enter().append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
   .data(function(d) { return d; })
 .enter().append("td")
   .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

On a subsequent update of my matrix 2d array, I want to catch (and do something with...) any table cell that changes.  Eg.

```
// updated matrix
var matrix2 = [
   [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
   [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
   [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 999999999],
   [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];

// bind the new data
var tr = d3.select("table").selectAll("tr")
   .data(matrix2, function(d) { return d[0]; });

var cells = tr.selectAll("td")
   .data(function(d) { return d; });

var updatedCells = rows.filter(function(d,i) {
   // HOWTO get previously bound value for cell???
   var prevCellValue = null;
   return prevCellValue != d;
} );
```

In the update selection resulting from a join, is there a way to retrieve the previously bound value for a given selection?  Once I've called `selection.data(newData)`, it seems like I've lost the previously bound data.  I can call `selection.data()` and temporarily store the output to a variable before binding new data to the DOM element, but it seems awkward (esp. for this 2D array example) to index the previously bound data within the anonymous function passed to, for example, the `selection.filter()`.

(BTW, I tagged "svg" because my actual example uses SVG elements, so I previously tried `this.textContent` in my `selection.filter()` function.  Unfortunately, `this.textContent` already had the newly bound data value for the given cell.)

**EDIT**: `this.textContent` "sort of" has the previously bound data, but it's potentially processed.  I'd prefer the raw, unaltered data if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 doesn't provide a way to get back the previously bound data. In your case, you might want to consider storing the data value in an attribute of the element it is bound to so that you can compare it later, i.e. something like

```
.data(...)
.attr("myvalue", function(d) { return d; });
```

Then you should be able to do something like

```
cells.filter(function(d) { return d3.select(this).attr("myvalue") != d; });
```

Comment: I may suggest to use [custom data-attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes) to store them.